# Change multiple ids to table variable sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sql query in which I am inserting multiple records based on how many Ids there are (few hundred):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ChangeBook (ID_Part, Price, ID_Client)
    SELECT d.ID_Parties, d.Price, a.TagId
    FROM dbo.Audit a CROSS JOIN
         (VALUES (1, 0.5), (3, 0.5), (5, 0.5), (6, 0.5), (8, 0.5), (9, 0.5)
         ) d(ID_Parties, Price)
    WHERE ID_Client in (2354, 4387, 5188, 5550, 1169, n+1);
```

this `(2354, 4387, 5188, 5550, 1169, n+1)` comes from manually copying ids from different select, let's say:
`SELECT TOP 10000 a.TagId FROM dbo.Audit`

so what I tried to do was to declare a table variable type so sql becomes:

```
DECLARE @Ids TABLE(Id INTEGER);

INSERT INTO @Ids SELECT TOP 10000 a.TagId FROM dbo.Audit
    
INSERT INTO dbo.ChangeBook (ID_Part, Price, ID_Client)
    SELECT d.ID_Parties, d.Price, a.TagId
    FROM dbo.Audit a CROSS JOIN
         (VALUES (1, 0.5), (3, 0.5), (5, 0.5), (6, 0.5), (8, 0.5), (9, 0.5)
         ) d(ID_Parties, Price)
    WHERE ID_Client in (2354, 4387, 5188, 5550, 1169, n+1);
```

but how do I then use `@Ids` instead of `2354, 4387, 5188, 5550, 1169, n+1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use a.TagId as ID_Client only exists in your target table.

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.ChangeBook (ID_Part, Price, ID_Client)
    SELECT d.ID_Parties, d.Price, a.TagId
    FROM dbo.Audit a CROSS JOIN
         (VALUES (1, 0.5), (3, 0.5), (5, 0.5), (6, 0.5), (8, 0.5), (9, 0.5)
         ) d(ID_Parties, Price)
    WHERE a.TagId in (SELECT Id FROM @Ids );
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `in (select . .  )`:

```
WHERE ID_Client IN (SELECT i.id FROM @ids i)
```